# The permissions granted to user 'MachineName\Administrator' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

(Revised based on comments below)

I know there's a ton of posts like this online and I've browsed many and found no useful help.

I have setup and configured SSRS many times and have not had this problem.  The setup is similar to other servers in the past (all stand alone servers - no AD).  I can log into Report Manager from a browser on the local server but when I try to access from my remote dev machine or from deploying a report from VS I get the above message.

This is how I'm trying to login which works on other servers but not this one.
http://Server IP/Reports

-Username: Administrator
-Password: admin password

I get the above error even though this is exactly the same as on other servers.

I should mention that I connect using a VPN to the network so I have access to the private IPs as well.

I also tried using he private IP

I also tried MachineName\Administrator

I also tried creating an SQL user with admin privileges and that did not work either.

This is a screenshot from a server where everything is working as expected.  Administrators had default permissions (Content Manager).  Users has browse:

[image]

This is a screenshot from the server that’s having permission issues.  I assigned all roles to both admin accounts

[image]

and then I added all roles to both admin accounts:

[image]

Now I can deploy from VS using the username "administrator".

and I made a little progress (i think...) trying to access report manager from my pc. From IE (run as admin) on my local pc I try to access report manager from this URL
http://server ip/Reports/browse/
-Username: Administrator
-Password: admin password

And now I gain access to server manager but cannot see any content.  When I click on the home button I get this error:

[image]

Any recommendations?

Comment: Have you completed running the configuration for SSRS in the SSRS Cfg Manager?

Comment: is that address correct, the default web portal is `http://myReportServerName/Reports`

Comment: SSRS manages its own catalog of users and permissions outside of Windows and Active Directory contexts. You'll need to login with a username (including a matching domain/machine name) that exists in the `ReportServer$InstanceName.dbo.Users` table.

Comment: Thanks @AlanSchofield.  Thanks that was part of the problem.  changing to http://ServerIP/Reports got me a little further.  I can login but not access content.  Based on the above comments I revised and added more to the post.  Please take a look and let me know if you have other ideas.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning.  I added more content and screenshots to the post above.  There’s a screenshot of the users assigned to a server that works as expected. Administrators and Users and I login as administrator.  The name of the server is XYZ and I tried logging in as XYZ\Administrator but that doesn’t work at all.  However, I can get in as just Administrator now, but can’t view any content.  Please see the revised post above.  Thanks.

Comment: spacedog We can see your Reports Server IP address on your screenshot ;). Have you gone through the SSRS Configuration Manager settings and verified everything? This was asked above by @rvsc48 but not answered.